# Caffeine cache: write() never get called

Tags: java, caching, caffeine

My cache is built with `writer`:

```
appsCache = Caffeine.newBuilder()
        .writer(this)
        .maximumSize(10)
        .expireAfterWrite(Duration.ofSeconds(64000))
        .build(this);
```

In my test, I'm loading 10 items and then waiting (with an infinite loop + sleep).

The problem is that `write()` never get called, even after calling `cleanUp()`

Why isn't `write()` been triggered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Writer](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine/wiki/Writer) called only when entry is changed

> The CacheWriter is notified **when an entry is created, mutated, or removed. A mapping that is loaded (e.g. LoadingCache.get), reloaded (e.g. LoadingCache.refresh), or computed (e.g. Map.computeIfPresent) is not communicated**

You aren't adding/removing entries.

Comment: I see, thanks. So when loading an item for the first time, I'll need to write it to DB myself, manually. Would that be a correct approach?

Comment: @yaseco read in link about write mode as **write-through cache the operations are performed synchronously and the cache will only be updated if the writer completes successfully**

Comment: I understand now, I shall use `put()` to trigger `write()`